# How to escape quotes and apostrophes in XmlNode C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am having to create an XML docuument for a third party and in their specs they say they need <>&" and ' escaped.  When I set the InnerText of an XMLNode I only get <> and & escaped automatically.  The " and ' are left alone.  After some digging I see these are valid which is why they are not escaped.  unfortunately for me the third party requires this.

I found that System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape wil escape all the characters I need but then when I set the InnerText of the XMLNode it escapes my ampersands in my escape characters I put in so I get & amp;quot; instead of & quot;.  There is no space between the & and the rest but I needed to do it to show in the text properly here.  I tried setting InnerXML instead of InnerText but that seems to unescape my string so it looks like it did before I manually escaped it.

```
XmlNode nameNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("name");
nameNode.InnerText(); = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(countyInfo.CountyName.ToUpper());
```

Any ideas on how I could handle this?

Comment: *"specs they say they need <>&" and ' escaped"* - Then their spec is broken and they need to fix their end of the system. XML does not become syntactically invalid when ' is not escaped, and that's the only thing that counts, really.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode your strings.

`& quot;` and `& apos;` are HTML entity encodings so they are asking you to HTML encode any string values.

Comment: "Modify the data" is not a solution.

Comment: It is if you have no control over the 3rd party code which seems to be the case here.

Comment: That would not help me anyway because the spec says I need to have it escaped as & quot; and & apos;

Comment: @DaveWade Telling the third party that they should start using an damn XML parser to parse XML would not be an option either, I suspect. Whatever they do, they are doing it wrong.

Comment: I've posted an update - & quot; and & apos; are HTML entities - they want HTML, not a pure string.